# Send money to multiple accounts via PayPal SDK or API

Tags: django, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, web-development-server

A website where users can buy digital products from other users and the host takes a cut out of those transactions. How to implement this system using the PayPal SDK or API?

Scenario:

1. One buyer with a personal PayPal account
2. One receiver with a personal PayPal account
3. The host with a business PayPal account

I wonder if it's possible that the buyer's money to be split and sent to the receiver and host account simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting a cut or fee might be possible if first using the partner-referrals API to onboard each receiver (seller). [Read about eligibility](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/#link-eligibility), and you must be an approved PayPal partner for all the available integrations that use it.

When using the partner-referrals API to onboard sellers,  specify [`PARTNER_FEE`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/#definition-rest_endpoint_feature) as one of the third_party_details `features` you are asking permission for.

When creating each order for buyers at checkout time, [specify a `platform_fees` object.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/immediate-capture/)

Any resulting platform fees will never be seen in the partner PayPal account, neither in sandbox nor live. They go directly to the associated bank account in the live environment. There will be an account report with the details.